# C++ breaking cyclic includes

Tags: c++

I probably know the answer already, but still I want to see if someone can come up with a better idea.

In larger library I have many classes cross referencing each other. I solve this usually by forward declaring those classes. However, for ease of use I usually define a ref type for classes that can appear in a shared_ptr like this:

```
class A : public B {
public:
  typedef std::shared_ptr<A> Ref;
};
```

which allows for much nicer references: `A::Ref a` instead of `std::shared_ptr<A> a`. The problem I see now is that using such a Ref requires to actually include that header file, leading to cyclic includes. I cannot define the Ref type in the file containing the forward declaration because XCode shows totally bogus values for vars using such a shared pointer.

What other options exist to do both: have the Ref defined on the real type, but do not require to include the header containing that type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can solve this exact problem, actually.

But if it is just to make your code prettier, you could change the logic a little bit.

Have a namespace Refs in which you define your typedefs. For example:

```
namespace Refs { typedef std::shared_ptr<::A> A; }
```

So, instead of `A::Ref`, you use `Refs::A`. I agree it's somewhat less logical, but it's not much longer to type, at least. Now, you can define such typedefs where required in your various headers and eventually forward declare them (provided you also forward declare the class before, of course).

**Other option**

But actually what I would do for this, if I were you, is using an alias (this requires C++11) for `std::shared_ptr`:

```
template<class T> using Ref = std::shared_ptr<T>;
```

Then you don't need to declare anything in any class or namespace. Just use `Ref<A>`, which is more flexible and clearer.

Comment: This is probably the way to go. Add a forward declaration to A in the above / enclosing namespace and put it in a header.

Comment: The Ref<> template alias is indeed the best solution here and fullfills the 2 conditions perfectly.